# Go how to get mouse/Cursor position on windows

Tags: windows, go, mouse

im trying to get the x and y position of the windows-cursor or windows mouse in Go.
I already found this package https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo which can listen for mouse events, but i cant find the code which is used for that.

```
func getCursorPosition() (x, y int) {
    return 0, 0
}
```

I want to replace "0,0" with the real cursor position.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you [read the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-vgo/robotgo)?

If you had, you might have noticed the function [`GetMousePos() (x,y int)`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-vgo/robotgo#GetMousePos).

Comment: How about cursor position?